# Calling menu option outside menu

Tags: android, menu

I have a Values.java class that is tied to multiple activities. Values.java can obtain the current running activity and uses that to open up the options menu associated with that activity. Each activity has an item labeled "start" and "cancel". How can this Values.java class call the start or cancel option of the current running activity? The reason I'm asking for this is because each activities' start or cancel button are heavily integrated with it's activity, i.e. one makes a thread, or is associated with values related to that activity. I'm not sure if what I'm asking for is possible on the android platform.

Comment: are the start or cancel buttons methods associated with a particular activity? If so you may consider using the command pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) in order to simulate function passing into the Values.java class, and pass in the start and cancel methods to this Values class

Comment: Yes, each activity's start and cancel methods might do something different. Values.class gets a signal, lets say start, and wants to perform the current running activity's start option of the optionmenu

Comment: Is an instance of Values being created by each class?

Comment: No. It's created from the first activity as a static class. All the other activities will access the information stored in Values. What I plan on doing right now is that when Values.class says "Call start", it will set a boolean to be true. In each activity I will make a thread in the onStart() method that will just loop, looking to see if any condition (i.e. start or cancel) is true and perform the certain action, then the thread will just sleep for like 1/4 to 1/2 second.

Comment: ok back, had some conflicting with threads so i decidedd to do a new approach. Is it possible for me to save the menu for the current running activity in Values.class and then call ((Activity) getCurrentContext()).onOptionsItemSelected(theMenu.findItem(R.id.start)); ? (theMenu is what Values.class saves the running activity's menu)